# Jersey 2.x does not contain WebResource and resource class. What can I use instead?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am trying to create a web API using Jersey. I am trying to run a method similar to this:

```
WebResource r = c.resource("http://localhost:8080/Jersey/rest/contacts");
```

However Jersey 2.x does not have a `WebResource` or `Resource` class. So what class can I use instead in order to have the uri `http://localhost:8080/Jersey/rest/contacts` as a parameter?
This will be ran in a `ContactClient` class

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the [Client API](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html) from the Jersey documentation. With Jersey 2.x you instead want to use [`WebTarget`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html). For example

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
Response response = target.request().get();
```

See the documentation I linked to for much more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

**JAX-RS 2.0 Client API**:
JAX-RS 2.0 introduces a ***new client API*** so that you can make ***http requests*** to your remote ***RESTful web services.***

It is a 'fluent' request building API with really ***3 main classes:***

1. Client,
2. WebTarget, and
3. Response.

**1. Making a simple client request**

**Jersey 1.x way:**

```
Client client = Client.create();
  WebResource webResource = client.resource(restURL).path("myresource/{param}");
  String result = webResource.pathParam("param", "value").get(String.class);
```

**JAX-RS 2.0 way:**

```
Client client = ClientFactory.newClient();
 WebTarget target = client.target(restURL).path("myresource/{param}");
 String result = target.pathParam("param", "value").get(String.class);
```

**2. Attaching entity to request**

**Jersey 1.x way:**

```
Client client = Client.create();
 WebResource webResource = client.resource(restURL);
 ClientResponse response = webResource.post(ClientResponse.class, "payload");
```

**JAX-RS 2.0 way:**

```
Client client = ClientFactory.newClient();
 WebTarget target = client.target(restURL);
 Response response = target.request().post(Entity.text("payload"), Response.class);
```